# gridview does not contain Defination for Current Row

Tags: asp.net

```
string companyID = grdClients.CurrentRow.Cells["CompanyID"].Value.ToString();
```

this is the error message:

> gridview does not contain Defination for Current Row and No Extention method excepting First Argument.

Comment: In which event are you having this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no property on GridView by the name of CurrentRow.  However,  you can use SelectedRow property to get the cell text.  You must pass an index and not a name to Cells as in code below.

I am assuming that the index of the cell you are getting is 2 ( you will have to plugin the appropriate index for your  scenario) .

```
 string companyID = grdClients.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
```